# Were all Vorlons telepathic?

Tags: babylon-5, vorlons

Most sapient races in the Babylon 5 continuity had some people among them with telepathic talent and some without (the former seems to be the minority in most of these species.) Were the Vorlons different in this regard? Is there anything in writing or on screen that confirms or disproves whether all Vorlons had telepathic gifts?

Comment: I’m not sure if it was ever definitely confirmed or not, but from what we know about Vorlons and telepaths, it would not surprise me if they did all have it.

Comment: <kosh>No.</kosh>

Comment: Weren't the Vorlons the source of the telepathic gene in the younger races in the first place?

Comment: All of the Vorlons *that we see* are telepaths. That's not necessarily true for all Vorlons.

Comment: Seeing Vorlons are only able t o communicate telepathically it would be logical to assume that in fact they are all telepaths.

Comment: @A.bakker Are they? Pretty sure Kosh mostly uses his suit's voicebox to talk. And by "talk" I mean "dumbfound listener with cryptic riddles".

Comment: #notallvorlons bro

Comment: @A.bakker The background noise you hear when a Vorlon speaks is their language.  They are capable of non-telepathic communication.  But we only see it translated telepathically or by their encounter suits.

Comment: @suchiuomizu but without they are dependent on their telepathy amongst each other.